"Latitude Grid Not Spaced Evenly" warning from NCEP-NCAR reanalysis 2m Air Temp raster
I am using air temperature data from the NCEP-NCAR reanalysis along with a country shape file to calculate mean air temperature by country. The NCEP-NCAR project has various air temperature rasters available, including one at air pressure level sigma 995 and another at 2m above the surface, both of which I downloaded. The documentation of this project states that the spatial coordinates of the files are 2.5X2.5 global grids. In R, when I check the resolution of the sigma995 raster file, I see that it conforms to the expected 2.5X2.5. However, when I check the resolution of the 2m raster file, I see a different result:
library("raster")
temp_raster_sigma995 = raster::stack("air.sig995.1961.nc")
res(temp_raster_sigma995)
[1] 2.5 2.5
temp_raster_2m = raster::stack("air.2m.gauss.1961.nc")
res(temp_raster_2m)
[1] 1.875000 1.904129

To extract mean values based on country, I use the exactextractr package. Below I run the extraction using both files and an independent country shapes file:
library("exactextractr")
library("sf")
library("raster")

temp_raster_sigma995 = raster::stack("air.sig995.1961.nc")
temp_raster_2m = raster::stack("air.2m.gauss.1961.nc")
country_shapes = sf::read_sf("country_shapes",layer="country")

sigma995_extracted = exactextractr::exact_extract(temp_raster_sigma995, country_shapes, fun = "mean")
|=======================================================================================| 100%
Warning message:
In .local(x, y, ...) :
  No CRS specified for raster; assuming it has the same CRS as the polygons.
two_m_extracted = exactextractr::exact_extract(temp_raster_2m, country_shapes, fun = "mean")
|=======================================================================================| 100%
Warning messages:
1: In new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) :
  GDAL Message 1: Latitude grid not spaced evenly.  Setting projection for grid spacing is within 0.1 degrees threshold.
2: In x@cpp$crop(y@cpp, snap[1], extend[1], opt) :
  GDAL Message 1: Latitude grid not spaced evenly.  Setting projection for grid spacing is within 0.1 degrees threshold.

When I run the extraction using the sigma995 air temp raster, I get a warning about no CRS specified. I independently verify that the CRS is the same between the shape file and the temp raster, so I think this is no big deal. However, when I run the extraction using the 2m air temp raster, I get an error that seems more serious, which I believe is related to the discrepancy in grid resolution shown above.
I also tried using projectRaster to change the 2m air temp file to a 2.5X2.5 grid and verify the change was successful:
temp_raster_2m_projected = raster::projectRaster(temp_raster_2m, res=2.5, crs=crs(temp_raster_2m))
res(temp_raster_2m_projected)
[1] 2.5 2.5

Now when I run the extraction I do not get the same warning message, but I do see a different GDAL warning that I'm not really sure what to make of:
two_m_projected_extracted = exactextractr::exact_extract(temp_raster_2m_projected, country_shapes, fun = "mean")
|=======================================================================================| 100%
Warning message:
In new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) :
  GDAL Error 4: `/tmp/RtmpjHSgT6/raster/r_tmp_2024-06-19_165850_20255_25153.grd' not recognized as a supported file format.

Finally, I compared the results of two_m_extracted and two_m_projected_extracted, and noticed that non-projected and projected results are slightly different. I included below the first line of a CSV file I export with the country name and temperature for the first few observations.
Output using the non-projected raster:
AA  299.055939  299.016663  299.817810  299.382507  

Output using the projected output:
AA  298.399994  298.299988  300.000000  299.099976

Is the GDAL warning Latitude grid not spaced evenly a big deal? It sounds fishy but also the qualifier Setting projection for grid spacing is within 0.1 degrees threshold indicates the coordinate discrepancy is not large. I'm also not sure why the 2m air temp. file I downloaded does not have 2.5X2.5 grid cells, while the sigma995 air temp. file does, and whether the rasterProject I performed is an appropriate technique to correct it.
EDIT:
The specific raster files I'm using can be found here (sig995 file) and here (2m file).
Here is the output of print for both files:
print(temp_raster_sigma995)
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 73, 144, 10512, 1460  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 2.5, 2.5  (x, y)
extent     : -1.25, 358.75, -91.25, 91.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
names      : X1961.01.01.00.00.00, X1961.01.01.06.00.00, X1961.01.01.12.00.00, X1961.01.01.18.00.00, X1961.01.02.00.00.00, X1961.01.02.06.00.00, X1961.01.02.12.00.00, X1961.01.02.18.00.00, X1961.01.03.00.00.00, X1961.01.03.06.00.00, X1961.01.03.12.00.00, X1961.01.03.18.00.00, X1961.01.04.00.00.00, X1961.01.04.06.00.00, X1961.01.04.12.00.00, ... 

print(temp_raster_2m)
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 94, 192, 18048, 1460  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1.875, 1.904129  (x, y)
extent     : -0.9375, 359.0625, -89.49406, 89.49406  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : X1961.01.01.00.00.00, X1961.01.01.06.00.00, X1961.01.01.12.00.00, X1961.01.01.18.00.00, X1961.01.02.00.00.00, X1961.01.02.06.00.00, X1961.01.02.12.00.00, X1961.01.02.18.00.00, X1961.01.03.00.00.00, X1961.01.03.06.00.00, X1961.01.03.12.00.00, X1961.01.03.18.00.00, X1961.01.04.00.00.00, X1961.01.04.06.00.00, X1961.01.04.12.00.00, ... 


Until you can give us links to the raster files you are using, could you at least print out the summary information for the raster objects, as shown by summary or print functions?

@Spacedman thanks for the suggestion. I edited the question.

As a first comment, please consider using terra because that package has now superseded the raster package.
The filename air.2m.gauss.1961.nc already suggests that the data is distributed on a gaussian grid, more specifically, I suspect on NCEP's T62 grid.
What that means is that the latitudes are not spaced evenly. We can investigate this by using the ncdf4 package to inspect the dimension values manually:
library(terra)
library(ncdf4)

url <- "https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis/surface_gauss/air.2m.gauss.1961.nc"
dst <- tempfile(fileext = ".nc")
download.file(url, dst)

nc <- nc_open(dst)

lons <- ncvar_get(nc, "lon")
lats <- ncvar_get(nc, "lat")

unique(diff(lons))
#> [1] 1.875
unique(diff(lats))
#>  [1] -1.888901 -1.899902 -1.902397 -1.903496 -1.903801 -1.904106 -1.904297
#>  [8] -1.904396 -1.904503 -1.904594 -1.904602 -1.904598 -1.904701 -1.904697
#> [15] -1.904800 -1.904799 -1.904699 -1.904760 -1.904730 -1.904740 -1.904730
#> [22] -1.904732 -1.904736


So while the longitudes are spaced evenly this is not true for latitudes.
Now, let's observe what happens when we open the file directly with terra:
r <- rast(paste0("/vsicurl/", url))[[1]]
print(r)
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 94, 192, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1.875, 1.904129  (x, y)
#> extent      : -0.9375, 359.0625, -89.49406, 89.49406  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#> source      : air.2m.gauss.1961.nc 
#> varname     : air (4xDaily Air temperature at 2 m) 
#> name        : air_1 
#> unit        :  degK 
#> time        : 1961-01-01 UTC
lats_terra <- unique(yFromCell(r, 1:ncell(r)))
unique(diff(lats_terra))
#> [1] -1.904129


Through GDAL, terra treats these latitude values as if they were spaced evenly because the differences are below the 0.1° thresholds. You can only judge in the context of your question if you are willing to accept this simplification. If you do and project the data to the regular spaced grid of the air.sig995.1961.nc file, keep in mind that you should select a proper resampling method, e.g.:
# reproject with terra
dummy <- rast("/vsicurl/https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis/Dailies/surface/air.sig995.1961.nc")[[1]]
r2 <- project(r, dummy, method = "bilinear")
print(r2)
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 73, 144, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 2.5, 2.5  (x, y)
#> extent      : -1.25, 358.75, -91.25, 91.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> varname     : air (mean Daily Air temperature at sigma level 995) 
#> name        :    air_1 
#> min value   : 220.1410 
#> max value   : 314.7626 
#> unit        :     degK 
#> time        : 1961-01-01 UTC



thank you for this helpful response!
